# TypeScript: Is there a way to type a function so that it returns different types of results dynamically according to it params

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a very contrived example so please bear with me:

I have a function `foo`. It takes an object of this type as its parameters

```
interface Foo {
  bar: number,
  baz: number,
  enabled?: boolean,
}
```

When `enabled` is not provided by the user or when it is false, `foo` would return an object of type `Result`

```
interface Result {
  result: number
}
```

so it just adds these two numbers as in

```
function foo({bar, baz}: Foo): Result {
  return {
    result: bar + baz
  }
}
```

Here is the question: When `enabled` is provide in the params and it is set to `true`, I want the function returns another type of result, where it has another field `isEqual`, which indicates if `bar` and `baz` is equal. so like

```
interface AnotherResult {
   result : number,
   isEqual: boolean
}
```

Here is how we can use this function

```
const {result} = foo({baz: 1, bar: 2})

// or

const {result, isEqual} = foo({baz: 1, bar: 2, enabled: true})
```

Ideally when the user include `enabled: true` in the params to `foo`, they can destructure  `isEqual` from the return value of `foo` and when they don't provide `enabled` or set `enabled: false`, they **cannot** destructure  `isEqual` from the return value of `foo`.

Here is my attempt but I cannot think of a way to dynamically determine the return value's type based on the params. I wonder if that is even possible with TypeScript

```
nterface Foo {
  bar: number,
  baz: number,
  enabled?: boolean,
}

interface Result {
  result: number
}

interface IsEqual {
  isEqual: boolean
}

type ResultWithIsEqualEnabled = Result & IsEqual


function foo({bar, baz, enabled = false}: Foo): ResultWithIsEqualEnabled {
  return {
    result: bar + baz
  }
}
```

Comment: i think the `IsEqual` interface should inherit `Result` interface, rather than combine then with `&` operator

Comment: or composition is better? Not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function overloads:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: number,
  baz: number,
}

interface FooEnabled extends Foo {
  enabled: true,
}

interface Result {
  result: number;
}

interface IsEqual extends Result {
  isEqual: boolean
}

function foo(foo: FooEnabled): IsEqual;
function foo<T extends Foo>(foo: T): Result;
function foo({bar, baz, enabled}: FooEnabled): Result | IsEqual {
  const result = baz + bar;
  
  if (enabled) {
    return {
      result,
      isEqual: bar === baz,
    }
  }

  return {
    result,
  }
}

const {result} = foo({
  bar: 5,
  baz: 5,
});

const {result: anotherOneResult, isEqual} = foo({
  bar: 5,
  baz: 5,
  enabled: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple return types for a function in typescript. For your example you can do it like this :

```
    function foo({bar, baz,enabled=false}: Foo): Result | AnotherResult {
       return (enabled==true)?{result: bar + baz, isEqual: true}: {result: bar + baz} ;
    }
```